# Code is not looping correctly when running on battery

Tags: battery, loop

```
static const int dry = 570;
static const int wet = 225;
static const int RELAY = 2;
static const unsigned long DELAY_1_S      = 1000;
static const unsigned long DELAY_1_MINUTE = DELAY_1_S * 60;
static const unsigned long DELAY_1_HOUR   = DELAY_1_MINUTE * 60;
static boolean watering = false;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RELAY, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int sensorVal = analogRead(A0);
  int percentageHumidity = map(sensorVal, wet, dry, 100, 0);
  Serial.print(percentageHumidity);
  Serial.println("%");
  if (!watering && percentageHumidity < 60){
    watering = true;
    Serial.println("Watering!!!");
    digitalWrite(RELAY, HIGH);
    delay(3*DELAY_1_S);
    digitalWrite(RELAY, LOW);
    watering = false;
  }
  Serial.println(DELAY_1_S * 10);
  delay(10*DELAY_1_S);
}
```

I have an analog reading at A0 from a capacitance water sensor. If the sensors read a value of 60% or less humidity it will activate a water pump. The water pump is connected through a 5v relay and the water pump has its independent power supply. For some reason, the code works when connected to the USB as intended, but when I power it with the battery it connects always the water pump.

Comment: Which board and which battery do you use? How are they connected?

Comment: Show your wiring.  If it works on USB but not on battery then it probably isn't the code that's the issue.  You got all the grounds connected?

Comment: Are your wet and dry values the same when running from battery? Have you determined if they should be changed?